# How to post multiple arrays to Web2py controller using Jquery ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, web2py

I am trying to post two arrays to my controller using Jquery ajax. below is part of my code:

```
arr1 = ['a','b','c']
arr2 = ['d','e'] 
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {arr1:arr1, arr2:arr2},
    url: url
});
```

what I am getting in my request.post_vars is:

```
{'arr1[]': ['a','b','c'], 'arr2[]': ['d','e']}
```

Why is there [] at the end of the dictionary key?! am I not passing the arrays the correct way?

Answer (score 1):

This is what I do for posting two variables.

```
var msg = "msg=" + JSON.stringify({
        "new": n,
        "del": d,
        });
    $.post('{{=post_url}}', msg, function(jdata) {
        var data = $.parseJSON(jdata);
```

It works as expected, and the JSON string is sent as the content of the variable 'msg'.

Comment: Oh right, I changed my suggestion.  I think that $.ajax will look for a {variable: content} type of object in json, and will use the variable as the variable in the HTTP POST, and the content as the content of that variable.  I always pass things in a single variable; try if it works.

Comment: now  get this weird thing {'data:[arr1][]': ['a','b','c']} in my post_vars

Comment: I have already tried stringfy, the problem with that is, the result is going to be passed as string to server and then i have to convert this string looking array back to an actual array and that is not a straight forward task. here is the post_vars now: `Storage {'msg': '{"arr1":[a,b],"arr2":[c,d,e]}'}` as you can see now the whole object is in string form.